# How to Get The Name of Day Based on Number In Month

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know we can get the name of day in week by using a code like this

```js
var d = new Date();
var days = ["Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"];
console.log(days[d.getDay()]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

but I need to get name of days from 3 random numbers in current month

```
 var arr = []
 while(arr.length < 3){
   var randomnumber=Math.ceil(Math.random()*30)
   var found=false;
   for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if(arr[i]==randomnumber){found=true;break}
  }
   if(!found)arr[arr.length]=randomnumber;
 }
```

can you please let me know how to do this in JS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is to genrate a date and then use `.getDay()` to get a day between 0-6 i.e. from `Sun to Sat`.

```
function returnDay(d, m, y){
    var year = y | 2015; // Making y an optional param.
    var d = new Date(m+"/"+d+"/"+y); // Pass inside any date if you have.
    var days = ["Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"];
    return days[d.getDay()];
}
```

Now all you need to do is

```
returnDay(16, 12, 2015); // Will return the day of 12/16/2015 (mm-dd-yy)
```

You can pass random date/month/year as well

Comment: Thanks void but this is returning undefined!

Comment: I hope you are passing the year as well.

Comment: I see now! in fact you pass the wrong parameters in your example! the middle number is for month so shouldnt be bigger than 12 at `returnDay(12, 16, 2015);`

Comment: Ohh yeah! My bad. Updating, btw is it working fine now?

Comment: by the way it is `returnDay()` not `returmDay()` :-)

Answer (score 1):

If the requirement is only to find the day name (in English) for any day of the current month then it can be done in one line of code:

```
 function getDay( day ) {
      return new Date((new Date()).setDate(day)).toDateString().split(' ').shift();
 }  

 // Test - DEC 2015 returns Tues, Mon, Thu, Fri
 console.info( getDay( 1 ));   
 console.info( getDay( 14 ));  
 console.info( getDay( 24 ));   
 console.info( getDay( 32 ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do like

```
var d = new Date(),
    n = d.getMonth(),
    y = d.getFullYear();

var days = ["Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"];
//Create new date from your No and Current Month+Year
var newDate = new Date("YourRandNo" + n + y);    
console.log(days[newDate.getDay();]);
```

Ex. If Rand No is `21` then new date is "`21-12-2015`"  and you can find day from date.

Comment: Hi Parth thanks for reply but I guess you didn't get the question exactly! My question is how to get the name of the Day based on the number in a Month? Please forget the Random part for now!